# Using GNU screen, how do I exec a process in response to a string of input coming from the remote application?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen, vt100

I'm using GNU screen to connect to a VT100 terminal server (DOS running in DOSEMU).  I want to configure escape sequences to exec a subprocess and quit a subprocess.  This would be similar to printcmd, except I would return the processes STDOUT to the remote server's STDIN.  I've read the GNU screen manual and understand the basics of exec, but I don't know how to make the exec happen on remote escape sequences.

Comment: I've tried using this simple example in .screenrc but it doesn't seem to work:  `!:sed -n s/.*Error.*/\007/p`   My idea is to use this type of inline filtering to send data back to the originating server process.